# navigation not using route variable value

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I have a route which specifies a language `:lang` here (Zend Framework 3):

```
'contact' => [
    'type' => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
                'route' => '/:lang/hello',
                'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                            'action' => 'contact',
                            'lang'       => 'en'
                ]
    ],
],
```

when i go to the webpage `http://localhost/pp/public/it/hello` it stores the `it` value into the `lang segment`.

The problem is on my navigation it says for the other areas as shown:

`http://localhost/pp/public/en/services`

should have been

`http://localhost/pp/public/it/services`

**Is there a reason why the `Zend\Navigation` is not using the value `it` instead of the default value `en` for the lang parameter of the route assembly**

Comment: If the parameter is not passed using the url helper like this: `'lang' => 'it'` it will fallback on the default, rather then checking the current value in your url.

Comment: @SvenBuis I would say that your comment should rather be posted as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

As per Sven Buis comment, you can manually add the current value to every url helper call, but that would probably not be the best way as it means adding code pretty much everywhere for a single purpose.

Another solution is to simply use the last parameter of the url view helper that allows to reuse the current route parameter (set it to true, default is false). I don't like this solution either, because you can have edge cases where all the default haven't been redefined, and that may break your code in places you would not expect.

You can have a look at the approach used in https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale (only works in ZF2 so far, I haven't had any time to finish my PR for ZF3). It uses the event system to hook up in the dispatch loop and set your language setting somewhere in there.